# What does SVD Entropy Capture?

Tags: intuition, entropy, svd

Looking at different definitions and types of Entropy, I [run into](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFUQFjAE&url=http://conference.scipy.org/scipy2010/slides/forrest_bao_pyeeg.pdf&ei=m4htUoqBH9DQkQfn3YCIAg&usg=AFQjCNFEtiVwf_56sG9-lrijHclw7dNi5A&sig2=q1hVGF5-oUe-_MPLqTBugQ&bvm=bv.55123115,d.eW0) the concept of SVD Entropy, which is defined as explained below.

What is the intuition behind the SVD spectrum? What do different frequencies in it capture? And most importantly **what does its Entropy measure, in relation to the original signal**?

> $\quad$*SVD Entropy*
>
> $\quad$$[17]$ defines an entropy measure using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). Let the input signal be $[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. We construct delay vectors as: $$\mathbf y(i)=[x_i,x_{i+\tau},\cdots,x_{i+(d_E-1)\tau}],$$$\quad$where $\tau$ is the delay and $d_E$ is the embedding dimension. In this paper, $d_E=20$ and $\tau=2$. The embedding space is then constructed by: $$Y=[\mathbf y(1),\mathbf y(2),\cdots,\mathbf y(N-(d_E-1)\tau)]^T$$$\quad$The SVD is then performed on matrix $Y$ to produce $M$ singular values, $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_M$, known as the singular spectrum.
> $\quad$The SVD entropy is then defined as: $$H_{SVD}=-\sum_{i=1}^M\overline \sigma_i\log_2\overline\sigma_i\tag{4}$$ where $M$ is the number of singular values and $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_M$ are normalized singular values by $\overline\sigma_i=\sigma_i/\sum_{j=1}^M\sigma_j$. SVD entropy is a scalar feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question begins with the word "intuitive", here's one way to describe it intuitively.

The SVD weights indicate how much of the data set is explained by each vector.

Entropy delivers the maximally-noncommittal data set at a given signal-noise ratio, that is to say, the most information with the least artefact.

So the SVD entropy is an indicator of how many vectors are needed for an adequate explanation of the data set.

You could say it measures feature-richness in the sense that the higher the entropy of the set of SVD weights, the more orthogonal vectors are required to adequately explain it.

Comment: Sorry for necro but while I agree that it " measures feature-richness " it does not on its own "an indicator of how many vectors are needed for an adequate explanation of the data set".

For example, you have a 50x50 matrix "a" where only element a(1,1) has value 1 and the rest are zero H=5.8E-13 but the "number of vectors needed to explain" is 1.

Comment: It's an intuition question so the point of the answer is to give a correct intuition not to cover corner cases like a matrix with only one element.

Comment: @Ilya, isn't $H=0$ in your example? Perhaps $H$ is roughly the $\log$ of the number of vectors needed to describe the data set ($H$ is the $\log$ of the rank when all singular values are equal)? Does this interpretation kind of make sense?

Comment: There's an old conference paper that provides some clarification here. The missing link is that exp(H) returns the effective dimensionality of the matrix. @Malkoun is correct that H=0 in Ilya's example, and exp(0) returns 1, which is the effective matrix rank. It works the same for an 8x8 identity matrix, where H=2.08 and exp(2.08)=8.00. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/37450697_The_Effective_Rank_A_Measure_of_Effective_Dimensionality

Comment: I sometimes surprise myself by my smart remark :) (just kidding). More seriously, thank you @GrahamS for bringing this article to our attention. It is an interesting concept, the effective dimensionality and it makes sense. If the entropy, i.e. the average number of bits, is say 10, then the effective dimensionality is the size of the set of all possible 10-bit words, i.e. $2^{10} = 1024$.